# How to flip tables in sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement wherein there are 2 tables (Staging & Target) in the same database.
Everytime data is first loaded in the Staging table. Now in second run data will be again first Loaded to the Staging table. Now I want to flip the tables using SQL query in such a way that after data is loaded into the Staging table make this changes

```
Staging becomes(flip) Target
Target becomes(flip) Staging
```

So ideally we will see both tables. But in actual at a time only 1 table has latest data.
Before opting for flip tables approach I have tried the sp_rename but that results in deadlock if someone tried to query Target table while it is being dropped and getting renamed.

Example,

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Target]','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [dbo].[Target] ; 
EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[Staging]','Target';
```

If we use the flip approach then there will be minimal chances of a lock. I tried to understand this flip tables concept and one approach I see is, it could be done using some kind of flag setting in SQL but not sure how. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/04/19/table-partitioning-in-sql-server-partition-switching/

Comment: How about just doing an ALTER TABLE SWITCH operation, for the whole tables. It doesn't require partitioning and switching entire table with another never required enterprise edition.

Comment: Thanks, @RichBenner link is helpful at least it provided some info on how things could be done in SQL.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi Problem I see with that approach is, lets say in 1st run  I will create 2 tbls Stg and Trg. Data will be loaded in Stg and then use ALTER TABLE SWITCH to load data from Stg to Trg. Now Stg is empty and Trg which initailly was empty now has data of Stg. Perfect for 1st run. 2nd run I can drop and Create Stg tbl which will have latest data but cannot do the same with Trg tbl, bcoz that's what I want to avoid droping of Trg tbl, once created it should persist & at same time it should get latest schema & data of Stg tbl & as far as I know for ALTER SWITCH one tbl needs to be empty.

Comment: How about using an intermediate work table? Load staging. Prod to work (prod now empty). Truncate work. Staging to prod.

Comment: Since the issue was with the 2nd run so before it starts Staging tbl is dropped and created with new schema and data in it. Using ALTER SWITCH load the old data of Prod i.e. Trg tbl to new tbl work so now Prod is empty and work has old data of Prod. Now truncate work and do ALTER SWITCH between Stg and Prod. But 2 issues here 1. I am making three tbls. 2. Before doing switch from Stg to Prod I will have to drop Prod reason Stg might have different schema now compared to old schema of Prod. So quite a lengthy process plus 3 tbls is not accepted in my scenario.